# Raphael Fill Opacity on member.mouseover

Tags: javascript, raphael, vml

I generated a VML file by using http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/SVGTOHTML_LIVE90.php. In the VML file there is a callback function section that determines events:

```
function callback(member)
{
   member.mouseover(function (e) {  this.ofill=this.attr('fill');this.attr({fill:'#000000'}); });
   member.mouseout(function (e) { this.attr({fill:this.ofill}); });
   member.click(function (e) { var thisPath=this.attr('path');alert('You just clicked on Element #'+this.id+'.To help you find it in the code its path starts with......'+thisPath);   });
}
```

As you may be able to see, the first line fills the VML shape hovered over with black. What I want to be able to do is change its fill-opacity instead.

I've tried:

```
this.ofill=this.attr('fill');this.attr({fill-opacity:'#000000'});
```

and other similar variations without success. Any ideas what I need to do here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No fill-opacities for VMLs, apparently. IE8 users will just have to see VML's solid colors :P

Answer (score 0):

**YOU NEED NUMBER FOR OPACITY NOT COLOR.**

Maybe something like this:

```
this.ofill=this.attr('fill-opacity');this.attr({'fill-opacity':0.5});
```

Comment: that's one of the first things I tried. Doesn't work. I'm thinking `this.ofill` might be the culprit.

Comment: there will probably be another variable, other than ofill for opacity